# Retrieving the phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

Where my application is installed I want to retrieve the phone number of that phone and then post it on the server. Is this possible?

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(
    Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

will this get me the number where my app is installed..?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Google is your friend.

Comment: can you help me with that.. the code part..

Comment: People will only put effort into responses if you put effort into your question. Requests to write code your code will probably be ignored, requests for help in a specific area or a specific sample would have a better chance of response.

Comment: 'TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number(); ' will this get me the number where the app is installed..?

Answer (score 1):

After retrieving the phone number, you can just send it to the server via Request.

```
Request request = new Request("your-server/your-file?your-parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to check the Phone Number? But one more way is there you can check sim card number.

Comment: after getting sim card number u can check whether that is ur sim or new sim, based on that u can do.

Comment: Making an application where i will be needing the phone number where my application will be installed. how do i do it with the sim card numkber..?

Comment: Why do you need the phone number? It's not a good way to identify a device and has big security/privacy concerns.  Down vote because your questions are poor, you haven't thought about this and you expect other people to do the work for you.  Have you tried flower arranging?

Comment: r u got ans for ur question or u need sample code for checking sim number?

Answer (score 0):

this prog is working for me

i think this will help u ....

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetSimActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button tmpbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tmpbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mobile Number : "+ telMgr.getLine1Number(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sim Serial Number : "+ telMgr.getSimSerialNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Also u have to add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```